# Javascript analog of css max-width, max-height 100%

Tags: javascript, image, resize, css

I need javascript analog (algorythm) for setting image width/height, which have effect when change max-width and max-height 100% for image resizing. (not using max-width and max-height css attribute, only width and height)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best possible solution, but one way to do something like this is to clone the element for which you're trying to determine the max-width and max-height.  Then render it invisibly and use the item's JavaScript properties after it has been rendered to determine the values, which will allow the browser to calculate them for you.

If you render an element as position: absolute and visibility: hidden, it should have the same attributes as if it were rendered as part of the page without being visible to the user.

Once rendered and calculated, you can then delete the element.

Comment: No, i need javascript calculation of width and height for customizing algorythm.

Comment: So i can get image size from backend

Comment: I'm unsure how what I suggested wasn't a javascript calculation of width and height.  The width and height may vary slightly from browser to browser, my method would simply allow you insight into what those values would be.